# In python search-and-replace (with fileinput) erases all my file content

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have a .py-file `my_file.py` that contains parameters and looks something like that:

```
input_folder = 'bla/bla/'
output_folder = 'out/put/folder/'
iterations = 20
```

I am writing a script that reads in this .py-file and when it encounters a user-defined line it changes the parameter in this line. So I managed so far to create this script

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("my_file.py", inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('output_folder ='):
        print("output_folder = '/new/file/path/'", end='') # for Python 3
```

What I would expect this script to produce is:

```
input_folder = 'bla/bla/'
output_folder = '/new/file/path/'
iterations = 20
```

Instead, it deletes all the lines in `my_file.py` that I haven't mentioned and leaves me with just this content:

```
output_folder = '/new/file/path/'
```

How do I achieve the desired result? Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `else` statement in your code, as the `inplace` argument will override all lines.
Something like this (you can change the `end` argument):

```
for line in fileinput.input(file_path, inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('output_folder ='):
        print("output_folder = '/new/file/path/'", end='\n') # for Python 3
    else:
        print(line, end="")
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, kind of obvious that I need the `else` statement, I should have known better

Answer (score 1):

Per: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html

> Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument inplace=True is
> passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file
> is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input
> file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it
> will be replaced silently). This makes it possible to write a filter
> that rewrites its input file in place.

What you observe seems to be the expected behavior. You just need to `print(line)` in an `else:` to echo the unchanged lines

```py
    else:
        print(line, end="")
```